# How do I use the FEATURETYPE for GetLegendGraphic request?

Tags: geoserver, wms, legend

I'm using the following SLD for Rendering a Polygon using GeoServer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
                       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
                       xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
                       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>City</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>City</Title>

      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>

          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">3</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>

      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Title>City</Title>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>

    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

When I make a `GetLegendGraphic` request, I get an image like: [image]

As you can see, it is showing both the FeatureStyles, because of which the top part of the Legend Graphic looks empty.

I know that there is a `FEATURETYPE` Parameter on the [GetLegendGraphic request](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/), but I can find an example of what I need to specify here.

How do I use the `FEATURETYPE` for GetLegendGraphic request?

Comment: Perhaps you should rather use ´RULE. I don't know how to use it but I would have a try with &RULE=City` But if FEATURETYPE is what needs to be used then I suppose that they should have names in the SLD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@user30184](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/30184/user30184) says the `FeatureType` parameter is for situations where you have multiple types of feature in a layer and only want the legend for one of them. In your case you have multiple rules and only want one of them to be shown. For this you want the `Rule` parameter:

```
http://.......&RULE=City
```

When the label of the Rule disappears, and you want to get it back, you can do so by using `forceLabels:on` as part of the `legend_options` in the request URL.

Comment: This kind of work; I see only Symbol, but the label of 'city' now disappears.

Comment: yes since you specified the rule name you become responsible for labelling it.

Comment: And how do I do? Is there some way of getting the Label with this Legend Graphic itself?

Comment: No, you can have all of them with labels or individual ones where you can add your own label - in an html table maybe?

Comment: I found a way to get it in the Legend Graphic by using `forceLabels:on` as the legendoptions in the url